# Focus jumps to mouse pointer while alt-tabbing

Tags: mouse-pointer

Alt+tab generally switches between windows, and I've found out that it works fine *as long as the mouse pointer isn't in the middle of the screen.* If it is, alt+tab switches to the last used window, but after half a second, *it switches focus to the window, the mouse pointer is pointing at!*

Am I the only one who finds that behavior extremely annoying? I mean, I know I can avoid that by parking my mouse above or below the alt-tab window line, but I fail to see how anyone could want this behavior.

This problem is reminiscent of [this one from eight years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198291/alttab-loses-focus), only it doesn't involve the mouse pointer. Is it really the same problem, or is this a different one?

Comment: The behaviour you describe is corresponding with the Window focus option "Focus on Hover". Default is "Click to Focus". Check the setting in Gnome Tweaks, Windows tab.

Comment: Hm, just checked - click to focus is actually selected. Maybe I just have an overly sensitive mouse pad?

Comment: You can check this by temporarily turning off tap to click: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by @vanadium, this is the way to go when I thought my mouse pad was dead:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false
```

Although, as it should, this disables the desired effect of tap-to-click, so this should be a temporary workaround.